# Centering my images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created an image slider using pure CSS using keyframe and animate, however I'm trying to centre my images using by margin: auto for left and right but it doesn't seem to centre it, can I move it around giving it actual pixel values.
Heres my CSS code:

```
.slide {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: em;
    padding: 3px;
    border-top: 2px dotted black;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
}
```

Heres HTML code:

```
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="images/horse4.jpg" class="slide">
            <img src="images/horse3.jpg" class="slide">
            <img src="images/horse2.jpg" class="slide">               
            <img src="images/horse1.jpg" class="slide">
    </div>
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` won't work with `absolute`ly positioned element.

Comment: `width: em;` is invalid.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2j6fo7wy/

Comment: Yes I was meaning to delete that, I did     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; and it managed to work, this is bad practice?